# Как заполнить пустоту при работе float?

Tags: html, javascript, css

Есть главный блок, в котором есть много блоков определенной ширины и высоты с `float:left`. Допустим, ширина блоков 250px, при уменьшении окна браузера, один из блоков "прыгает" вниз, а в верхней строке остается пустое место. Пример:

[image]

Увидел решение [тут](http://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/League%20of%20Legends). По сути, на данном сайте в 5 больших картинок, влазит 6 маленьких ну и т.д. Пробую реализовать на JS (не получается использовать свойства `min-width` и `max-width` при `float:left`), но что-то пока безуспешно, может, надо как-то по-другому делать?

[Пример на jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/wkrvbyv0/). Рабочий пример на SCSS: [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/2z42h2x0/). Хотелось бы CSS и JS ограничиться.

Comment: Что-то подобное у меня было. Обходился margin:0 auto; либо при 100% делал 99% ширину. Без всего примера ничего не скажу.
Попробуйте симитировать конструкцию на http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Держите. Добавлю в вопрос. http://jsfiddle.net/wkrvbyv0/

Comment: @hrvasiliy, как, по Вашему, всё должно происходить? Если блок больше размера пустого места, естественно он съедет вниз. Я не пойму что толком требуется.

Понял. Это нужно реализовать на JS

Comment: @Doofy как вариант. Только вот вы вопрос дочитайте, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Doofy Мне помогли, вот реализация на SCSS. Но хотелось бы другим путем. http://jsfiddle.net/2z42h2x0/